How to resolve an Unknown request from webview: {"type":"arFlameGraphRequested","command":"arFlameGraph.open"}
I am encountering an issue with my VS Code extension where a command sent from a webview is not being recognized by the extension. The command arFlameGraph.open is registered in the extension, but when the webview sends the message, it results in an "Unknown request from webview" error.
I have made several modifications to the codebase, including the package.json, launch.json, and various TypeScript files to ensure the command is registered and handled correctly. Below are the relevant code snippets and modifications made.
Relevant Code Snippets
package.json The command arFlameGraph.open is registered in the package.json file.

The extension.ts file contains the activation function where the WebSocket server is set up and the command arFlameGraph.open is registered.


open-flame-button.tsx
The open-flame-button.tsx file contains the code for the button that sends the arFlameGraphRequested message to the new package. This is from package table in common:

In addition I cant track the issue because the extension compiles in three webpack files.
I need to know where the error probably is
